# Ubuntu disconnecting my user when settings page open

Tags: 18.04, settings

I'm stuck with a very specific case of ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I'm using this OS for months ago, but today, from nothing, this problem started. Every time when I try to open settings of my pc, ubuntu just disconnect my user, and force me to put my credentials, in order to get logged again. It's only occur when I try to open settings, and when I disconnect, I can realize system very slow for a moment, which ends when I get myself logged again. I have no idea why this happen. Can you guys help me?

I'm the only user of this PC (it's my personal pc), and because of that, I'm a sudo user, just to give more details.

This is my [kernel log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tlwA.png) at the moment of crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching analyzing my kernel log, I discovered that's happening because some kind of incompatibility with my current video card driver. So, I just ran `sudo apt install nvidia-384` and it worked well.